# Problems with libxml2, undefined reference to `htmlParseFile'

Tags: c++, emacs

I have the following C++ code which I am trying to use to parse web pages into a simpler format:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libxml2/libxml/xmlexports.h"
#include "libxml2/libxml/xmlversion.h"
#include "libxml2/libxml/HTMLparser.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *filename = argv[1];

    std::cout << htmlParseFile(filename, "utf-8");
    
    return 0;
}
```

The LSP recognises the htmlParseFile function however when I try to compile I get the following error: `undefined reference to 'htmlParseFile'` The compile command I am using is `g++ ~/cpp\ test/test.cpp -I/usr/include/libxml2` so all the necessary files should be included. What am I doing wrong?

I tried adding the `-I/usr/include/libxml2` part of my compile command which changed the compiler error that I got from `libxml/xmlexports.h: No such file or directory` to the one I currently get.

**Edit 1**

The suggested post isn't helpful as I have already included the whole libxml2 library in the compile command and added the correct header files. I could be using the wrong include command which, for this specific purpose, will not be obvious to people trying to use this library. I need to know which files to include for this specific purpose.

Comment: Don't add this `-I/usr/include/libxml2`. You have a linker error. Add this `-lxml2`.

Comment: Just adding `-lxml2` results in the first error that I got.

Comment: The compilation worked when I added both of them :)